# how to make wi fi to work in ubuntu 14.04 and in dell n5010

Tags: wireless

Guys recently i installed ubuntu in my dell inspiron and after installing it my wifi is not working. Any help would be appreciated. 
And here are the results as asked.

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Kindly edit your question and include the result of this command: `lspci -vnn | grep Network`

Comment: Also go to `Settings` -> `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` tab and see if you have any additional drivers you can install.

Comment: Also try restarting network manager `systemctl restart network-manger.service`

Comment: @reversiblean it prints command not found

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot that you're on 14.04, then try `sudo service network-manager restart`. If that did not work `service networking restart`

Answer (score 0):

You should have it in additional drivers. But in case you do not, please read this.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Noteworthy excerpt:

> Broadcom STA Wireless driver (**Proprietary**) For Chip ID BCM 4311, 4312,
>   **4313**, 4321, 4322, 4331, 4352, 4360, 43142, 43224, 43225, 43227, 43228,
>   and others as suggested by Broadcom.
>
> The propietary Broadcom STA Wireless driver is maintained upstream by
>   Broadcom. As this driver is closed source, fixes in the driver itself
>   may only be provided by Broadcom. As a convenience, Ubuntu offers two
>   versions of this driver:
>
> The [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl) package aims to offer a later version for a
>   given release. Instructions for installation may be found later in
>   this article.
>
> The [broadcom-sta](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta) package aims to offer an earlier version for a given
>   release. For further installation instructions, please see here.